# How to make sure an element does not exist in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Can I use `maxOccurs="0"`?

Example:

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Do you have a better way for this?

Comment: It's the other way round. In XSD nothing can appear unless you explicitly permit it. There's no need to enumerate the millions of things that aren't allowed.

Comment: You are right. I have just learned, and its more powerful than DTD, where I couldn't express this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as long as `minOccurs="0"`, you could set `maxOccurs="0"`, but more commonly, you'd simply omit the element altogether to prevent it from appearing:

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```